# Запуск Python-скрипта в android приложении с помощью SL4A

Tags: android, python, android-studio, android-sdk

Необходимо запустить python-код из java кода android приложения. Нашел [SL4A](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a), решил попробовать через него . Скачиваю и пытаюсь добавить как модуль (File->New->Import Module...) проект sl4a/android/ScriptingLayerForAndroid, но возникает куча ошибок типа вот этой, как исправить не знаю.

```
...\utils\src\main\java\com\googlecode\android_scripting\interpreter\InterpreterDescriptor.java
Error:(19, 23) error: package android.content does not exist
```

P.S. Можно использовать и другой способ, не обязательно SL4A, главное чтобы не нужно было предустанавливать на телефон другое приложение/файлы.

Comment: Он же древний этот SLA4A, шесть лет назад пробовал, работал с пинками, похоже что его с тех пор и забросили. Мой совет, не тратьте время на это.